# Ghostscript not printing correctly A5 landscape pdf

Tags: printing, ghostscript

We have a little app detecting changes on some sftp server folders and printing automatically any new document. We set up this app, working for some years now in a warehouse in Europe, on a new warehouse in U.S but it fails to print correctly A5 documents.

The program uses ghostscript to do the printing and passes a set of arguments for A4 printers :

- `-dColorImageResolution=150 -dDownsampleColorImages=true -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dQUIET -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dNoCancel -sOutputFile="%printer%{0}" "{1}"`

And for A5 printers :

- `-sPAPERSIZE=a5 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dColorImageResolution=150 -dDownsampleColorImages=true -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dQUIET -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dNoCancel -sOutputFile="%printer%{0}" "{1}"`

The issue is that when we put the same configuration into our U.S printers, the pdfs in A5 landscape print on portrait orientation. We changed the configuration using options like dAutoRotatePages=(/PageByPage, /None, /All), tried remove dPDFSETTINGS=/screen and many other thing (I lost count sorry) and at best we can print the page in landscape but very offsetted on the right (like it doesn't understand anymore that the format is A5).

The printer is a Lanier PC600 I believe and here is the pdf I try to print:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VFnsBBnGf6MbJHdwmfD0Lc_QKGWznsFA/view?usp=sharing

Does someone has an idea on why this problem happens?

Thank you

Comment: Your command line uses a number of parameters which only make sense with the pdfwrite device. You have two devices selected, pdfwrite and mswinpr2, only the latter one will have any effect. You should remove all the parameters which aren't actually doing anything. As I've mentioned on numerous occasions, the mswinpr2 device, if setup not to display a printer chooser dialog, prints using the **default** configuration of hte printer. I would imagine the default of the US ones is different.

Comment: Hello and thank you @KenS. So yeah I see now how it is stupid to have both devices. I tried to remove -sDevice=mswinpr2 to only keep pdfwrite but doing this nothing was printing. I talked with the creator of the little custom program that uses Ghostscript and he told me that it uses Microsoft Print to PDF to actually do the printing, is it why pdfwrite doesn't work ?

Comment: I cannot see how Microsoft Print to PDF can be doing the printing, that **creates** a PDF file, it doesn't print it to a printer..... Ghostscript's pdfwrite device also creates PDF files from the input. If you actually want to print to a printer you need the mswinpr2 device (the devices are documented in the Ghostscript documentation at www.ghostscript.com). So basically you removed the wrong device. I can't see why you would 'print to PDF' from an application, then print the PDF to a printer rather than just print directly to the printer from the application.